# Random numbers when parameter changes in time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we want to simulate a poisson stochastic process which happens in time with a fixed rate $\lambda$. We can simulate this process generating the *delays* between discrete events randomly, sampling from an exponential distribution with fixed parameter $1/\lambda$. Then calculate the time of a given event summing over all the previous delays.

As an example, this is readily done in python with:

```
import numpy as np

def make_exp_inf_sequence(lambda= 70):
    x = 0
    while True:
        x = x + np.random.exponential(1/background)
        yield x
```

The following code snippet will sample from a poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$:

```
stream = make_exp_inf_sequence()
j = 0
for i in stream:
    j += 1
    if i > 1:
        print(j)
        break
```

Is it possible to extend this technique when the rate parameter change in time $\lambda = \lambda(t)$? What is the correct way to simulate stochastic processes with continuously changing parameters?

Thank you

Comment: An exact solution will depend on the form of $\lambda(t)$, but you could approximate it by a piecewise constant function and use your original approach on many small time intervals with a fixed value of $\lambda$ on each one.

Comment: Thank you @Karl. I'm interested in $\lambda(t)$ which are periodic in time, e.g. $\lambda(t) = A\sin(t)$. I'm aware that I can 'bin' the process but I am curious about the exact solution.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Simulation (see "inhomogeneous case")

Comment: Taking a look rn, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, one can use an acceptance-rejection method. Suppose $\Lambda=(\lambda(t))_{t\geq0}$ is bounded by $\kappa < \infty$.

1. Initialize with $t=0$.
2. Set $t \leftarrow t - \frac{1}{\kappa} \log U_1$, where $U_1 \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$.
3. If $\lambda(t)/\kappa \geq U_2$, where $U_2 \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ independently of $U_1$, then deliver $t$.
4. Goto step 2.

Classic reference: https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a059904.pdf.

Comment: This post might also be useful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/12/generating-a-non-homogeneous-poisson-process/.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you very much, especially for the references.

Comment: You're welcome.